# Convert UTC datetime to hexadecimal? value for GET request

Tags: r, datetime, httr

I include the `?` in the title because I am not exactly sure what conversion is going on here. As of the time of this posting, I receive this value from `Sys.time()` in `R`:

```
Sys.time()
[1] "2020-12-16 05:56:23 UTC"
```

I am fetching data from an API, and one of the additional params I can pass is a `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` `updated` value. For testing purposes, I am  using an API sandbox, so I was able to manually enter `2020-12-16 05:56:23` into an input field to run the query.

[image]

However, I am going to need to programmatically call the API in R. Fortunately, the API provides  the full call URL when running the API request from their sandbox. In this instance, I received the following URL string:

`https://api.<api-name>.com/v1/basketball/competitions/27693/matches?ak=<my-api-key>&updated=2020-12-16%2005%3A56%3A23`

So it went from the above timestamp, to `2020-12-16%2005%3A56%3A23`. My question is then twofold:

1. Using R's `httr::get()` function, is there a way I can pass a `params` list that simply passes something like `list(updated = '2020-12-16 05:56:23 UTC')`? Or do I need to re-create the URL string by converting `2020-12-16 05:56:23 UTC` into `2020-12-16%2005%3A56%3A23` somehow?
2. If I cannot pass the list item as described above, and I need to convert the datetime and insert it directly into the URL, how can I do this?

Comment: If you pass those values in the `query=` parameter, httr should URL encode those values for you. So `GET(..., query=list(updated = '2020-12-16 05:56:23 UTC'))`. (And the format is called URL Encoded, not "hexadecimal". It only effects non digit or character values).

Comment: okay, will give this a try. this definitely seems better than trying to encode it myself and pack it into the url manually.

Comment: yes this worked, thank you very much